# Grabar datos en tabla con jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

estoy empezando a programar en Html, necesito un programa que pueda grabar datos de un formulario a una tabla, al dar click en una fila de la tabla se marque de otro color y que al mismo tiempo aparezca un chexbox del lado izquierdo de la columna indexada. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Y que has intentado?, Por cierto en HTML no se programa

Comment: Esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones el lugar correcto para realizarla seria : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ o https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio. En su estado actual, esta no es una pregunta, es una solicitud para que alguien haga tu tarea escolar, o tu trabajo. No funcionamos así y me temo que la pregunta termine cerrada por la comunidad. Para más información, también puedes leer [ask]. Un saludo.